# Aligning the child elements with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have parent Flex container(`.content-flexbox-row`) with row direction, in which I am creating another flex with column direction(3 columns).

In 1st column I have 3 items and second column I have 1 item and third column I have 2 item.

The problem I am facing here is second and the third column taking center position based on the first column.

I want the 2 and 3 column data to start from the beginning instead of center.

```css
.content-flexbox-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  align-items: center;
}

.content-flexbox-row-last-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.content-flexbox-row .content-first,
.content-flexbox-row .content-second,
.content-flexbox-row .content-third {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: teal;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-flexbox-row .content-first {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-flexbox-row .content-second {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-flexbox-row .content-third {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.approver-names {
  height: 50px;
}

.content-second {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-flexbox-row">
  <div class="content-first">
    <div class="approver-names">
      <div>Raphael</div>
      <div>Head of Department</div>
    </div>
    <div class="approver-names">
      <div>Michael</div>
      <div>Head of Group</div>
    </div>
    <div class="approver-names">
      <div>Juan</div>
      <div>Head of Bears</div>
    </div>
    <span>+ ADD SELECTOR</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-second">
    <div class="approver-names">
      <div>I</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="content-third">
    <div class="approver-names">
      <div>Sancho</div>
      <div>Head of rows</div>
    </div>
    <span>+ ADD SELECTOR</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

PFB the plunker url to see the issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/J9zoXoQgbVphzvSVkmQ6?p=preview

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cewL42fd/

Comment: @stefan: exactly this one ...Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try `align-items: flex-start;` on the column container (`.content-flexbox-row`). You have it set on `center`, that's why the columns are centered.

Comment: I somehow missed that property :(